# How do I save an image to a png file?

Tags: swift

How do I load an image from specified url and save it to an existing local png file ? I'm trying to do it as follow but get an error

> The file couldn’t be saved because the specified URL type isn’t supported

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
try data?.write(to: URL(string: "icon.png")!)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all **never** use synchronous `Data(contentsOf` to load data from a server.

The error occurs because the URL has the wrong format

- A remote URL must contain a scheme and host (`http://server.com...`)
- An local URL in the file system must be created with `URL(fileURLWithPath:` and the path must start with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to asynchronously download a file:

```
extension FileManager {

    open func secureCopyItem(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) -> Bool {
        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dstURL.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstURL)
            }
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
        } catch (let error) {
            print("Cannot copy item at \(srcURL) to \(dstURL): \(error)")
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}

func download() {
    let storagePathUrl = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("file.png")
    let fileUrl = "https://server/file.png"
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: fileUrl)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: urlRequest) { tempLocalUrl, response, error in
        guard error == nil, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        guard FileManager.default.secureCopyItem(at: tempLocalUrl!, to: storagePathUrl) else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```